# One domain for each language liferay

Tags: localization, mapping, liferay

I am developing a liferay portal and I want to use different domains for each language. I have modified the servlet-mapping from web.xml but I ge this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> http://www.domain.ro/c/portal/protected in security constraint
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addConstraint(StandardContext.java:2869)
at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1244)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1357)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:855)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:345)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5161)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 10 more
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way, leave the web.xml as the original.

Which Liferay version?

Notice that new Liferay 6.2 allows to have differente language setting per site. In previous liferay version you have to create an ext plugin to hack the ServicePreAction class (not so easy).

Comment: I use liferay 6.1. Can't I make a hook for ServicePreAction?

Comment: Maybe yes, i don't remenber now, look at this http://www.liferay.com/it/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/15418262